# Flask receiving no data for HTML POST

Tags: python, flask

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if 'USER_TOKEN' in session:
            return make_response(render_template('index.html'))
        return make_response(render_template('login.html'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print 'data :', request.form
        return make_response(render_template('index.html'))
```

My `HTML` is

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" action="/" method="POST">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign In</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

When I submit data from HTML page, I see

```
data : ImmutableMultiDict([])
```

Why the data is missing?

Comment: I believe it is customary to include `name` attributes on your inputs in forms ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing field names (which are keys for `ImmutableMultiDict`, that's why it appears to be empty when form gets submitted).

change

```
<input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email">
```

to

```
<input name="<whatever_email_name>" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email">
```

and

```
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
```

to

```
<input name="<whatever_password_name>" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
```

Comment: That was the problem, How do you know that `name=` was needed? It is not even in Twitter-bootstrap documentation (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms). Thank you

Comment: There is nothing to do with twitter bootstrap. To give names to form fields is a part of HTML specification. Twitter bootstrap provides basic UI features to power your site right away before designers woke up.

Comment: I am facing the problem, but with Postman involved. What am I missing?